# how to implement MVC in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

Any references how to implement mvc in jquery.

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are already a few MVC frameworks out there that are designed to work well with jQuery, maybe they're worth a look to you.  Some suggestions:

http://www.javascriptmvc.com/

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

[edit] sorry to sound a tiny bit repetitive of the first answer - I guess SO didn't pop its usual "someone answered this while you weren't looking!" warning.

Answer (score 9):

you could try backbone: https://backbonejs.org/

> Backbone.js gives structure to web applications by providing models with key-value binding and custom events, collections with a rich API of enumerable functions, views with declarative event handling, and connects it all to your existing API over a RESTful JSON interface.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC 3 supports Multilingual. You can easily use jQuery with ASP.NET MVC.

Gives more dynamic look and feel to it, specially for pop up boxes, user input, routing to controller

Refer to this link

[For jQuery use and implement](http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2011/02/22/Progressive-enhancement-tutorial-with-ASP-NET-MVC-3-and-jQuery.aspx)

jQuery [jQuery site](http://jquery.com/)